# Decimal to vulgar fraction, Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, decimal, reverse-engineering, fractions

I have been trying to convert my Swift method to Kotlin and haven't gotten any help here:
[Decimal to vulgar fraction conversion method- need help converting from Swift to Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64532121/decimal-to-vulgar-fraction-conversion-method-need-help-converting-from-swift-to)

I figured I would change my question a little and see if I can get some help. I want help in reverse engineering/explanation of the code so I can make the conversion myself. I would learn more this way anyway.

The full code/story is linked above if interested.
I'm almost at the point of wanting to pay a freelancer to help with this. Please help :)
Additionally, you may need to know there is an array with super and subscript outputs for fraction inches that this method rounds to.
Need explanation of the following lines:

```
val whole = number.toInt() // Of course i know what this does :)
val sign = if (whole < 0) -1 else 1 // I converted this myself and believe this is correct Kotlin
val fraction = number - whole.toDouble() // And I know what this does

// need explanation from here down

for (i in 1..fractions.count()) {
    if (abs(fraction) > (fractions[i].1 + fractions[i - 1].1) / 2) {
        if ((fractions[i - 1].1) == (1.0)) run {
            return@run Pair("${whole + sign}", (whole + sign).toDouble())
        } else {
            return ("$whole" $fractions[i - 1].0, ${whole.toDouble() + (sign.toDouble() * fractions[i - 1].1))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Checked your original post. You would be better off trying to explain the lower part yourself to see where the gap is. As you seem to be a beginner, hint "the decimal points you think are numeric decimals are actually member access operators": How do you access members of a tuple in Swift? And when converting to Kotlin do tuples exist as a type? How would I access a member of Kotlin's version?

Comment: Sorry, but what is fractions?

Comment: @MorrisonChang you really nailed it! That was an exact confusion I had. Thank you! Will look further now :) - Dmitry my bad I forgot to elude to that, the full code is seen in the link at the top of my post. The "fractions" is an array of pairs of String and Double. It is used to provide the fractional output rounded to the nearest 16th on an inch. Example: Pair("\u215D", 5/8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I tend to write such computational functions as an extension function/property in kotlin, because in this way the usability will be increased.

#### NumberExt.kt

```kotlin
package ***

import kotlin.math.abs

/**
 * @author aminography
 */

val Double.vulgarFraction: Pair<String, Double>
    get() {
        val whole = toInt()
        val sign = if (whole < 0) -1 else 1
        val fraction = this - whole

        for (i in 1 until fractions.size) {
            if (abs(fraction) > (fractionValues[i] + fractionValues[i - 1]) / 2) {
                return if (fractionValues[i - 1] == 1.0) {
                    "${whole + sign}" to (whole + sign).toDouble()
                } else {
                    "$whole ${fractions[i - 1]}" to whole + sign * fractionValues[i - 1]
                }
            }
        }
        return "$whole" to whole.toDouble()
    }

val Float.vulgarFraction: Pair<String, Double>
    get() = toDouble().vulgarFraction

private val fractions = arrayOf(
    "",                           // 16/16
    "\u00B9\u2075/\u2081\u2086",  // 15/16
    "\u215E",                     // 7/8
    "\u00B9\u00B3/\u2081\u2086",  // 13/16
    "\u00BE",                     // 3/4
    "\u00B9\u00B9/\u2081\u2086",  // 11/16
    "\u215D",                     // 5/8
    "\u2079/\u2081\u2086",        // 9/16
    "\u00BD",                     // 1/2
    "\u2077/\u2081\u2086",        // 7/16
    "\u215C",                     // 3/8
    "\u2075/\u2081\u2086",        // 5/16
    "\u00BC",                     // 1/4
    "\u00B3/\u2081\u2086",        // 3/16
    "\u215B",                     // 1/8
    "\u00B9/\u2081\u2086",        // 1/16
    ""                            // 0/16
)

private val fractionValues = arrayOf(
    1.0, 
    15.0 / 16, 7.0 / 8, 13.0 / 16, 3.0 / 4, 11.0 / 16,
    5.0 / 8, 9.0 / 16, 1.0 / 2, 7.0 / 16, 3.0 / 8,
    5.0 / 16, 1.0 / 4, 3.0 / 16, 1.0 / 8, 1.0 / 16,
    0.0
)
```

#### Test

```kotlin
val rand = java.util.Random()
repeat(10) {
    val sign = if (rand.nextBoolean()) 1 else -1
    val number = rand.nextDouble() * rand.nextInt(100) * sign
    val vulgar = number.vulgarFraction
    println("Number: $number , Vulgar: ${vulgar.first} , Rounded: ${vulgar.second}")
}
```

Output:

> Number: 17.88674468660217 , Vulgar: 17 ⅞ , Rounded: 17.875
> Number: -56.98489542592821 , Vulgar: -57 , Rounded: -57.0
> Number: 39.275953137210614 , Vulgar: 39 ¼ , Rounded: 39.25
> Number: 13.422939071442359 , Vulgar: 13 ⁷/₁₆ , Rounded: 13.4375
> Number: -56.70735924226373 , Vulgar: -56 ¹¹/₁₆ , Rounded: -56.6875
> Number: 22.657555818202972 , Vulgar: 22 ¹¹/₁₆ , Rounded: 22.6875
> Number: 2.951680466645306 , Vulgar: 2 ¹⁵/₁₆ , Rounded: 2.9375
> Number: -8.8311628631306 , Vulgar: -8 ¹³/₁₆ , Rounded: -8.8125
> Number: 28.639946409572655 , Vulgar: 28 ⅝ , Rounded: 28.625
> Number: -28.439447873884085 , Vulgar: -28 ⁷/₁₆ , Rounded: -28.4375

---

#### Explanation

The explanation of the overall logic is a bit hard and I'll try to make it a little clearer. Note that in the below snippet, I've replaced the `fractionValues[i - 1]` with `fractionValue` for simplification.

```
// First look at the 'fractions' array. It starts from 16/16=1 down to 0/16=0.
// So it covers all the possible 16 cases for dividing a number by 16. 
// Note that 16/16=1 and 0/16=0 are the same in terms of division residual.

for (i in 1 until fractions.size) {
    // Here, we are searching for the proper fraction that is the nearest one to the
    // actual division residual. 
    // So, '|fraction| > (fractionValues[i] + fractionValues[i - 1]) / 2' means
    // that the fraction is closer to the greater one in the 'fractionValues' array 
    // (i.e. 'fractionValues[i - 1]').
    // Consider that we always want to find the proper 'fractionValues[i - 1]' and not 
    // 'fractionValues[i]' (According to the index of the 'for' loop which starts 
    // from 1, and not 0).

    if (abs(fraction) > (fractionValues[i] + fractionValues[i - 1]) / 2) {

        val fractionValue = fractionValues[i - 1]
        // Here we've found the proper fraction value (i.e. 'fractionValue').

        return if (fractionValue == 1.0) {
            // 'fractionValue == 1.0' means that the actual division residual was greater 
            // than 15/16 but closer to 16/16=1. So the final value should be rounded to
            // the nearest integer. Consider that in this case, the nearest integer for a
            // positive number is one more and for a negative number, one less. Finally, 
            // the summation with 'sign' does it for us :)

            "${whole + sign}" to (whole + sign).toDouble()
        } else {
            // Here we have 'fractionValue < 1.0'. The only thing is to calculate the 
            // rounded value which is the sum of 'whole' and the discovered 'fractionValue'.
            // As the value could be negative, by multiplying the 'sign' to the 
            // 'fractionValue', we will be sure that the summation is always correct.

            "$whole $fractionValue" to whole + sign * fractionValue
        }
    }
}

// Finally, if we are not able to find a proper 'fractionValue' for the input number, 
// it means the number had an integer value.
return "$whole" to whole.toDouble()
```

Comment: wow, I really appreciate the detailed post here and the time it took you to put this together! Thank you very much. I'm sure this will help a lot of people with Kotlin as this is the first.

Comment: what would be an easy way of making this an object? I tried putting all the code into a class to clean up my activity but Kotlin won't get over the errors. It's a bit over my head. Not a biggie if this isn't possible or easy, it works like a polished charm in the activity :)

Comment: It's a better way, as I mentioned above, to put this code in a file, for example I named it `NumberExt.kt`. So, I didn't mean to put these codes in your activity class. If you put them in a separate file, this will be available all over your project. Anyway, if you really want to make a class with it, no problem, I'll do it.

Comment: that makes more sense. I put it in activity cause I'm a noob haha. I'll do what you say, makes more sense! Thanks again dude, you rock!

Comment: hey aminography, how exactly do I use this globally as an extension I've been unsuccessful in calling it from a file or even a class. It is quite over my head i must say. Trying to neaten up my code a bit :)

Comment: It's quite easy to use these extensions. So, by putting a `.` right after a double number, IntelliJ should suggest the `vulgarFraction` by pressing `alt`+`enter`. Please see this: https://imgur.com/eO5ScaQ

Comment: If there is no success, try this: https://hastebin.com/tumuvapura.kotlin. To use it simply call the function: `NumberUtils.vulgarFraction(3.14)`.

Comment: Yes . notation should work but for some reason isn't... I must be doing something wrong somewhere. Once I remove the vulgar fraction code from activity it throws errors and I can no longer access .vulgarFraction from the .Kt file I put it in. I will use the object version you made, she is a work of art. And that solves it, thanks again aminography!